# JQuery Как при нажатии на кнопку назад вернуться к последнему состоянию предыдущей страницы?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, кэширование, header

Имеется сайт вопросов и ответов, в нем список вопросов, под ним кнопка "Показать еще", при нажатии на эту кнопку к списку, с помощью ajax, подгружаются новые вопросы (точно также как в сервисе "Ответы@Мейл"), т.е. страница меняется динамически. При переходе к вопросу, а затем обратно к списку с помощью кнопки браузера "Назад", необходимо получить последнее состояние страницы списка вопросов, как это можно реализовать? Подобный механизм реализован как в "Ответы Мейл", так и "Яндекс Кью", по моим догадкам они используют кэширование страницы, на уровне браузера. Как это реализуется?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) ?

Comment: Всю страницу в sessionStorage ? или как?

Comment: Ну у каждого вопроса должен же быть свой уникальный id ? Сохранить туда только id первого и последнего из загруженных вопросов. При повторном заходе - достать их, и по этим id загрузить всё, что хранится между ними. P.s. может есть более простой способ, а я о нем не знаю)

Comment: А если страницу просто так обновят, по F5, должны ли показываться последние загруженные? А когда не должны показываться последние загруженные?

Comment: Точно так же как в Ответы@Мейл или Кью. Попробуйте на этих сервисах пролистать вопросы как можно ниже, перейти в любой вопрос, и затем вернутся обратно, Вас перекинет на страницу в том же самом состоянии, в каком вы просматривали её ранее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По сути при нажатии на "показать еще", надо загружать вопросов на целую страницу (равносильно нажатию на кнопку следующей страницы). Надо в параметр адреса записывать ?offset=n где n это количество загруженных вопросов. При загрузке вызывать popState и записывать в него текущую урлу. Ну и ловить onpopstate, из него брать урлу и по оффсету из параметра загружать нужное количество вопросов)

Comment: Спасибо, рассмотрю как один из вариантов

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант можно хранить страницу пагинации, на которой находится пользователь и количество отображаемых записей в localStorage

```
const key = "pagination";
const pagination = {
  page: currentPage, // записываем текущую страницу пагинации
  countQuestion: countQuestion // записываем к-ство отображаеммых вопросов
};

localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(pagination));
```

В момент загрузки страницы проверятьесть ли в localStorage данные пагинации по ключу, если есть, то в ajax запросе мы указываем какие именно данные нам необходимо получить c сервера

```
const paginationData = localStorage.getItem(key);

if(paginationData) {
   const result = JSON.parse(paginationData);
   const currentPage = result.page;
   const countQuestion = result.countQuestion;

   // ES6 более кратко
   //const {currentPage, countQuestion} = JSON.parse(paginationData);

   if(currentPage && countQuestion) {
     ajax...
   }
}
```